# using react-navigation in react-native 0.59.10

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler

I'm making a project with react-native 0.59.10
when I wanna install reac-navigation, react-native-gesture-handler and react-native-reanimated .
I got error and project does not built, should I use a specific version of each of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `react-native 0.59.10` latest versions of that libraries might not be compatible.

According to your requirements,

- `react-native-gesture-handler` version between `1.1.0` & `1.4.0`. [Check this official documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gesture-handler#react-native-support) for more information.
- `react-navigation` requires `react-native@^0.54.x`. Since `react-navigation@3.x` depends on the new `React.createContext` API, which was added in `react@16.3.x`.